# Output ID of instance

Tags: java, static, instantiation

I want to create 5 instances of a class, but no more (error message when instantiated 6th time). Also I want to be able to call each objects fields(id in this case) in custom order, so I need reference variables for those objects which I don't because my getInstance() had to be a static method. How can I output the id's of each object for example in reverse order they were created. Hope this makes sense, if not just tell me how you would normally do this kind of stuff.

```
public class JustFive {
    private static int i=0;
    private int id;
    public JustFive(int n){
        this.id=n;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         getInstance();
         getInstance();
         getInstance();
         getInstance();
         getInstance();
    }
    private static JustFive getInstance() throws Exception{
        if(i<5) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i+" instance created ");
            return new JustFive(i*1000);
        } else
            throw new Exception("Can't create more than 5 instances of this class");
    }
    private int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create five `JustFive` instances, place them in a `List<JustFive>`, then use a `Comparator<JustFive>` to sort them in descending order by `id`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<JustFive> jfs = Arrays.asList(getInstance(), getInstance(), getInstance(), getInstance(), getInstance());
    Collections.sort(jfs, new Comparator<JustFive>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(JustFive o1, JustFive o2) {
            return -1 * new Integer(o1.id).compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
    });
    for (JustFive justFive : jfs) {
        System.out.println(justFive.getId());
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
1 instance created 
2 instance created 
3 instance created 
4 instance created 
5 instance created 
5000
4000
3000
2000
1000
```

Comment: That works.. but how can I get, say, only the third instance's private id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     List<JustFive> elems = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
         elems.add(getInstance());
     }
     // print in reverse order
     for (int i = elems.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
         System.out.println(elems.get(i).getId());
     }
}
```